# Clicking an element changes it's position

Tags: javascript

I have a function that moves a *point* into the center of the screen when clicked. The function that does this looks like this:

```
// Animates the slider
animate: function (startTime, distance, duration, options, completedFn) {

    // Animate
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {

        // Get our offset
        var now = Date.now(),
            timeDelta = Math.min(now - startTime, duration),
            timePercent = timeDelta / duration,
            offset = timePercent * distance;

        // Get our position
        var position = options.finalX + offset;

        // Create the transform
        options.transform = 'translateX(' + position + 'px)';

        // Add to our element
        options.element.style.transform = options.transform;

        // If our time is less than our duration
        if (timeDelta < duration) {

            // Animate again
            service.animate(startTime, distance, duration, options, completedFn);

        // If our time has exceeded our duration
        } else {

            // Set our options for scrolling
            options.finalX = position;
            options.oldX = options.currentX;
            options.currentX = options.currentX + (distance / options.width);

            // Invoke our callback
            completedFn();
        }
    });
},

// Moves the current active item to the center
moveToCenter: function (e, options, animate, completedFn) {

    // Exit if we are scrolling
    if (options.started)
        return;

    // Get the central position 
    var target = e.target,
        rect = target.getBoundingClientRect(),
        distance = options.center - rect.left - ((50 - 18) / 2), // Make these variables?
        positive = rect.left > options.center;

    console.log(rect);

    // If we should animation
    if (animate) {

        // Get our start points
        var distance = options.center - rect.left - ((50 - 18) / 2), // Make these variables?
            now = Date.now(),
            duration = Math.abs(distance) / 1;

        // Animate our elements
        service.animate(now, distance, duration, options, function () {
            completedFn(target);
        });

    // Otherwise
    } else {

        // Update the current position
        options.currentX = distance / options.speed;

        // Move our elements
        service.updateDragElement(options);

        // Invoke our callback
        completedFn(target);
    }
},
```

The line that is playing with me is:

```
distance = options.center - rect.left - ((50 - 18) / 2), // Make these variables?
```

50 is the width of the clickable element, 18 is the width of the actual *point*.
[Here is a codepen so you can see the issue](http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/EypKyX?editors=0010).

When you load the pen, if you click the point to the right of the pink square it will scroll into the pink square.
The issue is, if you click it in the center of the *point* it will actually scroll to the exact position the last *point* was in, but if you click it to the left or right of the *point* (but still clickable) it will be slightly off to the side that you clicked it at.

I am a little confused as to why this is happening because when I invoke **moveToCenter** the *point* hasn't moved yet so it should have the same position regardless of where I click in the clickable element.

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I don't think that I understood your question fully, but I was able to center everything right.

First of all disable `body` padding :

```
body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Then change your distance to:

```
distance = options.center - rect.left - 18/2
```

I hope this will help.

**EDIT**

Ok, I just didn't understand. The problem here is that bubble center and outer box is different elements. Test it with `console.log(e.target)`. You use `getBoundingClientRect()` to find the element which has to be moved and, in this case, it moves differently. If you don't need the outer box then you can change:

```
      <a href="#" ng-click="moveToCenter($event, true)">
        <div class="point" ng-class="{ 'active': item.active }" style="background-color: {{ item.color }}" ng-click="moveToCenter($event, true)"></div>
      </a>
```

To:

```
      <a href="#" ng-click="moveToCenter($event, true)" class="point" ng-class="{ 'active': item.active }" style="background-color: {{ item.color }}">
      </a>
```

This way only the bubble would work as a clicking area.

Comment: ok I have updated the codepen (I have drawn a box around the clickable area. If you click in the center, it will move to the pink box and be centered correctly. But if you click anywhere else inside the box you will find it doesn't quite line up. That is the issue.

Comment: I need the outerbox unfortunately (because the point inside changes size depending on position, although that part is not set up yet), but you are correct. I changed the `e.target` to `angular.element(e.target).parent()[0]` and changed `distance = options.center - rect.left - 18/2` to `distance = options.cetner - rect.left - 50/2`. There is a slight issue with positioning, but it doesn't matter where I click in the box now.

Comment: actually, I just did a screenshot and they are now exactly in the center, so that's good. Cheers.